# weird behaviour of globals() and locals() in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I create a simple code. 
For example

```
x = 50

def func(x):
    x = 2
    print 'Changed local x to', x

func(x)
```

Then I type globals() and expect to see the list of global variables
Instead I get a weird output like this below. Why? I use python 2.7, in jupyter. Everything else works fine. And this behaviour of globals() always happens . Same with locals().

```
{'In': ['',
  u"x = 50\n\ndef func(x):\n    print 'x is', x\n    x = 2\n    print 'Changed local x to', x\n\nfunc(x)\nprint 'x is still', x",
  u'globals()',
  u"x = 50\n\n   def func(x):\n       x = 2\n       print 'Changed local x to', x\n\n   func(x)",
  u"x = 50\n\ndef func(x):\n   x = 2\n   print 'Changed local x to', x\n\nfunc(x)",
  u'globals()'],
 'Out': {2: {...}},
 '_': {...},
 '_2': {...},
 '__': '',
 '___': '',
 '__builtin__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>,
 '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>,
 '__doc__': 'Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment',
 '__name__': '__main__',
 '_dh': [u'C:\\Users\\user'],
 '_i': u" x = 50\n\n def func(x):\n    x = 2\n    print 'Changed local x to', x\n\n func(x)",
 '_i1': u"x = 50\n\ndef func(x):\n    print 'x is', x\n    x = 2\n    print 'Changed local x to', x\n\nfunc(x)\nprint 'x is still', x",
 '_i2': u'globals()',
 '_i3': u" x = 50\n\n    def func(x):\n        x = 2\n        print 'Changed local x to', x\n\n    func(x)",
 '_i4': u" x = 50\n\n def func(x):\n    x = 2\n    print 'Changed local x to', x\n\n func(x)",
 '_i5': u'globals()',
 '_ih': ['',
  u"x = 50\n\ndef func(x):\n    print 'x is', x\n    x = 2\n    print 'Changed local x to', x\n\nfunc(x)\nprint 'x is still', x",
  u'globals()',
  u"x = 50\n\n   def func(x):\n       x = 2\n       print 'Changed local x to', x\n\n   func(x)",
  u"x = 50\n\ndef func(x):\n   x = 2\n   print 'Changed local x to', x\n\nfunc(x)",
  u'globals()'],
 '_ii': u" x = 50\n\n    def func(x):\n        x = 2\n        print 'Changed local x to', x\n\n    func(x)",
 '_iii': u'globals()',
 '_oh': {2: {...}},
 '_sh': <module 'IPython.core.shadowns' from 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\shadowns.pyc'>,
 'exit': <IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall at 0x27d0a90>,
 'func': <function __main__.func>,
 'get_ipython': <bound method ZMQInteractiveShell.get_ipython of <ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object at 0x0272F9D0>>,
 'quit': <IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall at 0x27d0a90>,
 'x': 50}
```

Comment: That's IPython doing that.  You are seeing how they do it behind the scenes :)

Comment: Jupyter / IPython create all kinds of weird-looking variables for internal use and partially for convenience (like `exit`).

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is indeed the global variables defined in your interpreter session. There are a few more of them than you expected! That's because the interactive interpreter uses some variables for its own purposes, such as keeping track of past inputs and outputs.

Some of the globals you're seeing (like `__builtins__` and `exit`) are a documented part of the Python language. Others are implementation details specific to your particular interpreter or shell environment, and may or may not be documented anywhere.

As for `locals`, it's only useful inside a function. At the top level of a module, it will return exactly the same dictionary as `globals` (including all the interactive crud if you're running it interactively).

Comment: Thank oyu. Is there a condensed format perhaps , that is more readable to the amateur user?

Comment: `%who` and `%whos` show the variables that you've created in this session.